# Combine coverage reports of different languages

Tags: python, go, code-coverage, codecov

I have 2 different test coverage files one is for Go (coverage.out) and other is for Python (.coverage).
I want single combined report from these 2 coverage files.
One of the solution I know is to upload these files into https://codecov.io and codecov will automatically merge it for us.
But I want to combine these reports locally, is there any way to do this locally?

Comment: Just be aware there's probably no _perfect_ way to do this, since different tools tend to measure coverage in different ways, and even when using the same method (i.e. branch coverage), branches across languages aren't always equivalent. But you can probably get close.